# Checkout Sourceforge CVS into a directory?

Tags: cvs, sourceforge

It's been a while since I've checked out a SourceForge CVS project, but now I cannot seem to do it easily anymore? Using cvs 1.12.13-MirDebian-11 on Ubuntu 14.04...

So, as per the instructions I have, first I try this:

```
$ cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@gmerlin.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/gmerlin login
Logging in to :pserver:anonymous@gmerlin.cvs.sourceforge.net:2401/cvsroot/gmerlin
CVS password:
```

... which I find a bit weird, since if I remember correctly, I was never asked for a password when I did this anonymous login on SourceForge for cvs?? Anyways, I just press enter here... Then I do:

```
$ cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@gmerlin.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/gmerlin co -P gavl
cvs checkout: warning: cannot write to history file /cvsroot/gmerlin/CVSROOT/history: Permission denied
cvs checkout: Updating gavl
cvs checkout: failed to create lock directory for `/cvsroot/gmerlin/gavl' (/cvsroot/gmerlin/gavl/#cvs.lock): Permission denied
cvs checkout: failed to obtain dir lock in repository `/cvsroot/gmerlin/gavl'
cvs [checkout aborted]: read lock failed - giving up
```

If I remember correctly, at this step in the past, `cvs` would have typically checked out the project into my current directory; but here it seems to want to write to `/cvsroot` directory, which doesn't exist on my system?

So how do I tell CVS to check out the above project in my current directory?

Comment: I've just tried those commands and the checkout worked fine. Are you still having the problem?

Comment: i have the same problem